# What do the input device monitor watch?

Tags: audio, monitoring

I open pavucontrol when playing a music on speaker.

[image]

Click the `input Devices` ,`line in` and `front microphone` ,`rear microphone` are all unplugged,so What do the input device monitor--`Monitor of Family 17h(Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo` watch?It is watching the output device --`line out` ?

[image]

```
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_09_00.6
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfccc0000 irq 60"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:09:00.6"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: no)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: no)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: yes)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 365, available: no)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pulseaudio, every sink (audio destination, output) has an associated source (audio source, input) that is called **monitor**.

For some reason, your audio hardware provides a sink that is called "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh)". That's an unusual name, and probably shows only up because your hardware manufacturer put some generic names into the BIOS.

You didn't tell us what sinks you have, so I would assume that this is just the generic "Builtin" sink if your hardware, that can output to different ports, including the "Line out" that you show, and probably others.

So the associated monitor source will mirror whatever audio you output into this sink, no matter if the sink has "Line out" or some other port activated.

It has nothing to do with the generic input source (which you say has as ports Line In, Front Mic, and Rear Mic).